# Random variable - probability calculation

Tags: probability

[image: []

For $1$,  I was thinking $P(X(1-X)<\frac{1}{4})=P(-X^2+X-\frac{1}{4}\lt 0)$. Should this probability be $1$ since $-X^2+X-\frac{1}{4}$ is negative on (0,1) except at $\frac{1}{2}$? For $2$, I don't understand what I am calculating, could someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Your answer to 1 is correct.  Part 2 looks like a typo.  I think they must mean $P\left(\frac{X}{1-X}<\frac{1}{4}\right)$

Comment: $-x^2+x-\frac14<0$ can be sammerized as $P(-(x^2-\frac12)^2<0)$. Yes, you´re right, that $P(  -(x^2-\frac12)^2<0)=1$

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @saulspatz that would make more sense, in that case, we would have $P(\frac{X}{1-X} \lt \frac{1}{4})=P(X<\frac{1}{5})=\frac{1}{5}$?

Comment: @funmath That's right.